# Take action if remote server responds to ping

Tags: bash, scripts, ping

I have a network attached storage (NAS) at home where I store pretty much all my media stuff (songs, videos, etc). I would like to mount it to a local directory in my notebook automatically every time I login at home so before mounting it I need to do a ping to see if it is answering (which means I'm home).

I already have the script to mount it (see below) but I have two questions:

1) How to use the answer from ping in order to see if its answering? I believe I have to use grep together with the ping command, but since I'm a new *nix user I'm not very fluent with it yet.

2) Where is the best place to put this script?

The mount command I have is this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //myIpAddress/remoteDir /media/MyLibrary -o username=myUsername,password=myPassword,domain=myDomain,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for grep or anything like that, just do this:

`ping -c 4 foo && sudo mount ...`

This basically uses the fact that ping returns true if the ping works, the -c limits it to 4 pings before returning. You can also do something if ping fails like this:

`ping -c 4 foo || echo "FAILED!"`

The other thing to consider is why you're mounting on login and not in your fstab, there are some good guides to mounting smb file storage online:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide

http://www.mattvanstone.com/2006/06/automatically_mounting_smb_sha/

Comment: I thought that I needed to test to see if the server is online before mounting otherwise I would have problems. However, I just added the stuff in fstab and tested with wireless off or my NAS off and it worked pretty well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you re-edit your question to be less about smb, we can make this question and answer more useful for future readers. There is already I think questions for smb mounting.